# Spring & Thymeleaf form

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

adding in form is trivial when I have only one object like here:

```
        <form th:action="|#{group/save}/${id}|" th:object="${groupForm}" method="post" class="col m8 s8 offset-m2">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="input-field">
                    <input th:field="${groupForm.name}" id="name" type="text" required="required"/>
                    <label for="name">Nazwa:</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn-success" type="submit" name="save">Wyślij<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

but let's assume that groupForm have list of customer

```
public class Customer{
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nick;
}
```

How can I add 5 Customers into list in class Group? I want to achive in one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Group class looks something like this:

```java
public class Group {
    private List<Customer> customers;
}
```

Try this:

```xml
<input th:field="*{customers[0].name}" type="text" required="required"/>
<input th:field="*{customers[1].name}" type="text" required="required"/>
<input th:field="*{customers[2].name}" type="text" required="required"/>
<input th:field="*{customers[3].name}" type="text" required="required"/>
<input th:field="*{customers[4].name}" type="text" required="required"/>
```

Comment: @JonsWacke Mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, that's how we say "thank you" here at SO.